# How to execute a script periodically without using crontab?

Tags: command-line, cron

How to execute a script periodically like crontab does but without using crontab?

Please note this that the executed script should not fire with another script and schedule it with 'sleep' command, what I expect to have same functionality as crontab but it should not be present in crontab list and should not be stop when terminal or session ended,

*crontab exactly but without croning it.*

Comment: I am afraid if you don' t want to use crontab *and* don't want to run a script, you are out of options. I guess else crontab would not exist. Possible options might depend on what the script should be triggered by; what defines the period of time.

Comment: what does the script do exactly? It sounds like you want a kernel module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modern option is to use a `systemd` timer unit.  This requires creating a `systemd` unit which defines the job you want to periodically run, and a `systemd.timer` unit defining the schedule for the job.

Assuming you want to run the job as regular user, put these files in `$HOME/.config/systemd/user`:

**my-job.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Job that needs periodic execution

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/your/script
```

**my-job.timer**

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer that periodically triggers my-job.service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=minutely
```

Then enable the newly created units, and start the timer:

```
$ systemctl --user enable my-job.service my-job.timer
$ systemctl --user start my-job.timer
```

To verify that the timer is set:

```
$ systemctl --user list-timers
NEXT                         LEFT     LAST                         PASSED UNIT         ACTIVATES
Wed 2016-11-02 14:07:00 EAT  19s left Wed 2016-11-02 14:06:37 EAT  3s ago my-job.timer my-job.service
```

`journalctl -xe` should show log entries of the job being run.

Refer to `man systemd.timer` for the many options for configuring timer behaviour (including randomised starting, waking the computer, persistence across downtime, timer accuracy, etc.), and to `man systemd.unit` for excellent documentation on `systemd` and `systemd` units in general.

Answer (score 2):

You could run a script with `at` and have it reschedule itself as its final instruction.  For instance like this:

```
$ cat > $HOME/my.job <<END
do this
do that
cat "$HOME/my.job" | at now + 5 minutes
END
$ sh ~/my.job
```

To stop the job, remove it from the `at` queue:

```
$ atq
5       Wed Nov  2 11:25:00 2016 a zwets
$ atrm 5
```

Or simply remove the file `my.job` so the next execution of `cat "$HOME/my.job"` will error so `at` will not be invoked and the rescheduling doesn't happen.

Comment: ...Which is actually equivalent to sleep 5 mins.

Comment: @JacobVlijm how is this equivalent?

Comment: We should wait for OP' s opinion, but I assume he does not literally mean "sleep", but refers to a time interval, set from a script. You might be right however.

Comment: @JacobVlijm `at` does not block and enter sleep, instead it schedules the job for a future time. It is just like `cron`, but then 'single-shot'. The job isn't attached to a terminal (the way a sleeping `bash` script would be, unless you disown or nohup it), so survives logout and, more importantly, survives reboot.

Comment: He mentions sleep in the comment on heemayl's answer. On second thought I agree however it is actually what he asks for. +1

Comment: @JacobVlijm I also took that to be OP's intention, hence the rescheduling 'trick'. I'm now thinking of a way to do it _without_ having the job file, but it creates a Gödelian situation, as in: define a string which as its last instruction echoes _itself_ into the `at` command. :)

Comment: Yeah, I read that, edited my comment, but you were quicker :)

Comment: could also use `at -f "$HOME/my.job" now + 5 minutes`