# Swap config files at certain times

Tags: scripts, schedule

I am trying to make a script that switches files at different times of days so that my settings are pulled at different times like a day mode and a night mode.

If I have a file 1, 2, and 3 which 3 is a group of settings for my server. I want to switch out 1 to become 3 from 8am to 6pm. then I want 2 to become 3 from 6pm to 8am automatically. How can I do this though shell script? I just want to basically do a `cp -v 1 3` then `cp -v 2 3` on a schedule how would I accomplish this? thanks in advance!
I don't want to do it through cron i want to do it through shell script only, if possible!!

Comment: Why not through cron?

Comment: If not via cron, then: https://askubuntu.com/q/844533/158442

Comment: Yes you can do it via script only; the script sleeps for xx hours on a cycle, but why?  `cron` is more resource efficient. You realize if you switch configs, whatever processes using them will probably need restart (to read the altered config) as they'll likely be reading/using the old config (inode)

Comment: Because I'm trying to make it a self contained shell script that i can save on various servers and just run the shell when I want from putty real quick. It is a random thing. More detail on what im doing is running a Zcash miner in ubuntu. and one pool pays good when it finds block but rarely finds blocks so when i see its been 24-48 hours since they've found a block i just want to run the script and switch pools. Because generally once they got that long without a block they are  close to finding on and then i wanna switch back to my more steady pay out pool after say 12 hours

Comment: If you guys think cron is the way to go still ill do it and yes the process needs to be restarted but i know how to restart it in the script when the script runs.